# Dickey-Fuller test (variable with trend)

Tags: time-series, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have to perform a Dickey-Fuller test with Stata but I'm not sure if the command "dfuller ln_divyield" is correct, in fact the variable ln_divyield shows a decreasing trend over time. What command should I use in this case? Thank you
[image: trend over time of the variable ln_divyield]

[image: Dickey-Fuller test]

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that this site is not intended to be a resource for specific software questions. Please consider rephrasing your question in more general terms, perhaps regarding use of a test different from the DF as appropriate for your data.

Comment: @DJohnson, why ask about another test if the question is clearly about the Augmented Dickey Fuller test.

Comment: +1 to @DJohnson. You might also a bit more on why the test result surprises you. I'm voting to leave open to give the OP time to revise toward on-topic.

Comment: @RichardHardy  There are other tests for unit roots besides the ADF such as Phillips-Perron. I was merely suggesting ways to generalize the OPs query beyond Stata commands.

Comment: I have to perform a school project where is required the Dickey-Fuller unit root test, but I have some difficulties in choosing the best test options referring to my own data.

Comment: You can ask about how the DF test works, how the result can be consistent with the figure, how to interpret it, etc. All those questions would be on topic here; asking what Stata commands to use is off topic.

Comment: @DJohnson, my point was that to make the post valid the author does not need to change the topic more than necessary. If the ADF test is of interest, it's perfectly valid to ask about it, and there is no need to expand on to other tests which are not of interest. On the other hand, I did not oppose your idea regarding specific Stata commands.

Comment: @RichardHardy  I agree but, as noted, the goal of my suggestion was to help the OP find ways to more broadly rephrase their question beyond Stata commands, leaving the choice of whether or not to expand the question in this way up to them. I don't think there is any reason to view this as problematic. The fact is that many OPs can ask quite specific questions when what they really need to do is step back and examine things from a less narrow and pedantic POV. I'm sure you've observed this behavior in many cases on CV.

Comment: @DJohnson, got your point, but my critique addressed a different problem. I think it was the way your original comment was phrased that I found problematic; instead of suggesting to elaborate on what the problem with the ADF test was, you encouraged to consider another test; I found this to be besides the point.

Comment: @RichardHardy  You are very clearly an expert with deep domain expertise in time series and I empathize with the "occupational hazards" associated with this. It can't hurt to point out that what is clearly "besides the point" to you may not be so clearly "besides the point" to someone else without the same levels of depth and expertise. Acknowledging these differences eliminates the possibility for "gotcha" kinds of reactions to what seem, to you, to be missteps but which, in reality, are simply more broadly applied and generalizable approaches to problem solving and decision making.

Comment: @DJohnson, thanks for the discussion. Also, any and all critique was not intended to be personal (but it seems there was no misunderstanding to that respect, which is very good). If I had to make any personal points, they would be positive towards you due to your active contributions to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @DJohnson mentioned, there are a few other tests of note:

1. **ADF** - augmented Dickey Fuller, which you noticed. Note you could do something radical like putting in a linear trend, i.e., Dx = A +
   Bt + C x(t-1) + stuff
2. Flipping H0 and H1, **Makalainen** test.  This is a really good one (and for cointegration, ADF corresponds to Johansen, while
   Makalainen corresponds to Nyberg).
3. **KPSS** - meant to be non-parametric. I believe it is thought to be not as powerful as hoped and is not mentioned much in
   practice. This is a variant on Makalainen which is much more commonly implemented but questionably better.
4. **Variance ratio tests**. These tests whether the scaled T-period variance is proportional to the 1-period variance. With proper scaling a Brownian motion should have a variance ratio close to one. Mean reversion results in values far below one and explosiveness above. Ho and MacKinlay established asymptotic CI. Typically people will plot these and effectively do multiple tests at once (which is theoretically *not kosher*). While this is know to have low power too the test is informative and it is known that the lower the value of var ratios the higher the returns of simple mean reversion strategies. (Both in-sample). In other words there may be more refined CI that can be established when it comes to testing for RV trading strategies.

**In ADF**

H0: Unit root

H1: mean reverting / stationary

We always try to reject or not reject H0. The power of the test is low.

**In Makalainen/KPSS**

H0: Stationarity

H1: Unit root.

There is some work as well on both.

BTW, your series doesn't look so stationary. It may have been but you have at least 10+ years of trendiness. The results look reasonable to me. In stats speak, you cannot fail to reject the null (it's non-stationary).

Comment: I should have mentioned Makalainen is not widely available. Instead a more complicated non parametric version called KPSS is much more widely implemented.